# Volatility surface interpolation for Black-Scholes delta hedging

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility, volatility-surface, interpolation, volatility-interpolation

A general question for interpolation method for implied volatility between tenors. I've recently stumbled accross a dataset from http://www.math.ku.dk/rolf/Svend/, and I would like to interpolate the volatility surface, in order to try and make a delta-hedge expirement. However, I was wondering what interpolation method is best to use. In general I was considering if bi-liniar interpolation is the beth methods, but does anybody have any guidance in what to use?

Comment: your link doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cubic polynomial curvature would be the most simple one.Otherwise,many practitioners are actually using a Gaussian process interpolation,which is more sophisticated.

Comment: What is / do you mean with a Gaussian process interpolation?